# Azure-Dashboard issues and improvement

Tags: azure, azure-dashboard

customization Azure dash board with the query and other things as per the maintained activity  required is a cost and vm

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

•   You can surely create a query for showing a VM’s status and its cost on the **Azure dashboard** through the **log analytics** dashboard queries. It can visualize all your saved log queries, giving you the ability to find, correlate, and share IT operational data in the organization. But for that purpose, you will need to create a custom dashboard through the Azure portal that includes the operational data that is important to manage your Azure VMs. Thus, create a dashboard by referring to the link below for more details: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/tutorial-logs-dashboards#create-a-shared-dashboard

•   Thus, once a dashboard is created, you will have to visualize a log query for that purpose. In the log analytics workspace, select logs option and then paste a **kusto query** for the results of the requested VM for its usage and costs. This query includes the ability to edit a query on multiple lines, selectively execute code, context sensitive Intellisense, and Smart Analytics. Open Log Analytics by selecting Logs in the Azure Monitor menu. It starts with a new blank query. Once the above is done, then paste the query as given in the sample below. It returns processor utilization records for both Windows and Linux computers, grouped by Computer and TimeGenerated, and displayed in a visual chart. Click Run to run the query and view the resulting chart.

```
‘ Perf 
  | where CounterName == "% Processor Time" and ObjectName == "Processor" and InstanceName == "_Total" 
  | summarize AggregatedValue = avg(CounterValue) by bin(TimeGenerated, 1hr), Computer 
  | render timechart ‘
```

•   Once done, save the query and give it a name and save it. Once done, pin it to the dashboard and you can see it every now and then as well as export it and share it with anyone. You will have to modify the above query according to your requirements.

Please refer to the documentation link below for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/tutorial-logs-dashboards#visualize-a-log-query